# Logistic Regression in R: glm() vs rxGlm()

Tags: r, logistic-regression, glm, revoscaler

I fit a lot of GLMs in R. Usually I used `revoScaleR::rxGlm()` for this because I work with large data sets and use quite complex model formulae - and `glm()` just won't cope.

In the past these have all been based on Poisson or gamma error structures and log link functions. It all works well.

Today I'm trying to build a logistic regression model, which I haven't done before in R, and I have stumbled across a problem. I'm using `revoScaleR::rxLogit()` although `revoScaleR::rxGlm()` produces the same output - and has the same problem.

Consider this reprex:

```
df_reprex <- data.frame(x = c(1, 1, 2, 2), # number of trials
                        y = c(0, 1, 0, 1)) # number of successes

df_reprex$p <- df_reprex$y / df_reprex$x # success rate

# overall average success rate is 2/6 = 0.333, so I hope the model outputs will give this number

glm_1 <- glm(p ~ 1,
             family = binomial,
             data = df_reprex,
             weights = x)

exp(glm_1$coefficients[1]) / (1 + exp(glm_1$coefficients[1])) # overall fitted average 0.333 - correct

glm_2 <- rxLogit(p ~ 1,
                 data = df_reprex,
                 pweights = "x")

exp(glm_2$coefficients[1]) / (1 + exp(glm_2$coefficients[1])) # overall fitted average 0.167 - incorrect
```

The first call to `glm()` produces the correct answer. The second call to `rxLogit()` does not. Reading the docs for `rxLogit()`: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/machine-learning-server/r-reference/revoscaler/rxlogit it states that "Dependent variable must be binary".

So it looks like `rxLogit()` needs me to use `y` as the dependent variable rather than `p`. However if I run

```
glm_2 <- rxLogit(y ~ 1,
                 data = df_reprex,
                 pweights = "x")
```

I get an overall average

```
exp(glm_2$coefficients[1]) / (1 + exp(glm_2$coefficients[1]))
```

of 0.5 instead, which also isn't the correct answer.

Does anyone know how I can fix this? Do I need to use an `offset()` term in the model formula, or change the weights, or...

(by using the `revoScaleR` package I occasionally painting myself into a corner like this, because not many other seem to use it)

Comment: I'm not 100% sure here (I do not use revoScaleR) but can you try using fweights instead of pweights? Some discussion around pweights and fweights can be found here: https://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/1413514-stata-fweights-versus-pweight. In this case, fweights seems more appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

**I'm flying blind here because I can't verify these in RevoScaleR myself -- but would you try running the code below and leave a comment as to what the results were?  I can then edit/delete this post accordingly**

**Two things to try:**

- Expand data, get rid of weights statement
- use cbind(y,x-y)~1 in either rxLogit or rxGlm without weights and without expanding data

---

If the dependent variable is required to be binary, then the data has to be expanded so that each row corresponds to each 1 or 0 response and then this expanded data is run in a glm call without a weights argument.

I tried to demonstrate this with your example by applying labels to `df_reprex` and then making a corresponding `df_reprex_expanded` -- I know this is unfortunate, because you said the data you were working with was already large.

Does `rxLogit` allow a `cbind` representation, like glm() does (I put an example as `glm1b`), because that would allow data to stay same size… from the [rxLogit page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/machine-learning-server/r-reference/revoscaler/rxlogit#formula), I'm guessing not for rxLogit, but rxGLM might allow it, given the following note in the [formula page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/machine-learning-server/r-reference/revoscaler/rxformula):

> A formula typically consists of a response, which in most RevoScaleR
>   functions can be a single variable or multiple variables combined
>   using cbind, the "~" operator, and one or more predictors,typically
>   separated by the "+" operator. The rxSummary function typically
>   requires a formula with no response.

Does `glm_2b` or `glm_2c` in the example below work?

```
df_reprex <- data.frame(x = c(1, 1, 2, 2), # number of trials
                        y = c(0, 1, 0, 1), # number of successes
                        trial=c("first", "second", "third", "fourth")) # trial label

df_reprex$p <- df_reprex$y / df_reprex$x # success rate

# overall average success rate is 2/6 = 0.333, so I hope the model outputs will give this number

glm_1 <- glm(p ~ 1,
             family = binomial,
             data = df_reprex,
             weights = x)

exp(glm_1$coefficients[1]) / (1 + exp(glm_1$coefficients[1])) # overall fitted average 0.333 - correct


df_reprex_expanded <- data.frame(y=c(0,1,0,0,1,0),
                                trial=c("first","second","third", "third", "fourth", "fourth"))

## binary dependent variable
## expanded data
## no weights
glm_1a <- glm(y ~ 1,
              family = binomial,
              data = df_reprex_expanded)


exp(glm_1a$coefficients[1]) / (1 + exp(glm_1a$coefficients[1])) # overall fitted average 0.333 - correct

## cbind(success, failures) dependent variable
## compressed data
## no weights
glm_1b <- glm(cbind(y,x-y)~1,
              family=binomial,
              data=df_reprex)

exp(glm_1b$coefficients[1]) / (1 + exp(glm_1b$coefficients[1])) # overall fitted average 0.333 - correct


glm_2 <- rxLogit(p ~ 1,
                 data = df_reprex,
                 pweights = "x")

exp(glm_2$coefficients[1]) / (1 + exp(glm_2$coefficients[1])) # overall fitted average 0.167 - incorrect

glm_2a <- rxLogit(y ~ 1,
                 data = df_reprex_expanded)

exp(glm_2a$coefficients[1]) / (1 + exp(glm_2a$coefficients[1])) # overall fitted average ???

# try cbind() in rxLogit.  If no, then try rxGlm below
glm_2b <- rxLogit(cbind(y,x-y)~1,
              data=df_reprex)

exp(glm_2b$coefficients[1]) / (1 + exp(glm_2b$coefficients[1])) # overall fitted average ???

# cbind() + rxGlm + family=binomial FTW(?)
glm_2c <- rxGlm(cbind(y,x-y)~1,
              family=binomial,
              data=df_reprex)

exp(glm_2c$coefficients[1]) / (1 + exp(glm_2c$coefficients[1])) # overall fitted average ???
```